# (NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'detail' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['<int:id>/']). please help me to remove this error

Tags: python, html, css, django

It is a multiple image program in which we can add multiple image at one time to see grouped photos. Error during template rendering
In template C:\Users\a\dev\mysite\templates\base.html, error at line 15
I am able to open my admin panel but i am not able to  my files. thus please help me to find error:
models.py

```
    from django.db import models
class Post(models.Model):
    title           = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description     = models.TextField()
    image           = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/', null=True, blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class PostImage(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.post.title
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Post, PostImage
def blog_view(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog.html', {'posts':posts})
def detail_view(request, id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    photos = PostImage.objects.filter(post=post)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {
        'post':post,
        'photos':photos,
    })
```

admin.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, PostImage
class PostImageAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model=PostImage
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PostImageAdmin]
    class Meta:
        model=Post
@admin.register(PostImage)
class PostImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

base.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-DhY6onE6f3zzKbjUPRc2hOzGAdEf4/Dz+WJwBvEYL/lkkIsI3ihufq9hk9K4lVoK" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Multi Image Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container py-4">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

blog.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2">
    {% for post in posts %}
    <div class="col mb-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="view overlay">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{post.image.url}}"
                    alt="Card image cap" >
                <a href="#">
                <div class="mask rgba-white-slight"></div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{post.title}}</h4>
                <p class="card-text">{{post.description}}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'detail' post.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Read More</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!---card-->
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

detail.html

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-mdb-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    {% for p in photos %}
    <li data-mdb-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-mdb-slide-to="{{forloop.counter0}}" class="{% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} active {% endif %}"></li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    {% for p in photos %}
    <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.counter0 == 0 %} active {% endif %}">
      <img
        src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/slides/041.jpg"
        class="d-block w-100"
        alt="First slide"/>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
  <a
    class="carousel-control-prev"
    href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
    role="button"
    data-mdb-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a 
    class="carousel-control-next"
    href="#carouselExampleIndicators"
    role="button"
    data-mdb-slide="next" >
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from posts import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^youadmin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', views.blog_view, name='blog'),
    url(r'^<int:id>/', views.detail_view, name='detail'),
] + static (settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `url` function which expects you to use regex to capture arguments, to capture an integer your patterns should be like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^youadmin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', views.blog_view, name='blog'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/', views.detail_view, name='detail'),
]
```

But i would recommend you to use the `path` function instead, which doesn't require regex:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('youadmin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.blog_view, name='blog'),
    path('<int:id>/', views.detail_view, name='detail'),
]
```

Comment: it is showing ImportError: cannot import name 'path' from 'django.urls'
help me about this

Comment: @AAKASHSINGLA You might be using an older version of Django, use the first option then.

Comment: first option is also not working guide me about first option     help me about the second option what i have to do for install  or any other solution

Comment: @AAKASHSINGLA Whats not working in the first option?

Comment: now 127.0.0.1:8000 this is showing that page not found but it does not show noreversematch error now what should i do?

Comment: @AAKASHSINGLA are you sure you are talking about the first option I have given in my answer? I have not changed anything in this pattern `url(r'^', views.blog_view, name='blog'),`. Please use the **first block of code** in my answer.

Comment: its working but it is not showing the image. help me about this

Comment: @AAKASHSINGLA in your for loop over the images you have set the src attribute to `https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/slides/041.jpg` set it to `{{ p.image.url }}`

Comment: in detail.html by changing this src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/slides/041.jpg"  to src="{{ post.image.url }}" does not give me any effect.

Comment: @AAKASHSINGLA Your loop is `{% for p in photos %}` and you are writing `{{ post.image.url }}` does that make sense to you?

Comment: This also after changing src="mdbootstrap.com/img/new/slides/041.jpg" to src="{% for p in photos %}" does not give me any effect. Help me about this

Comment: if you can help me regarding this, then please help me. I am not able to show the images or multi-images

Answer (score 0):

You must include a trailing slash at the beginning of your **urls** like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/youadmin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^/', views.blog_view, name='blog'),
    url(r'^/<int:id>/', views.detail_view, name='detail'),
]
```

It's also possible that an instance of `Post` with `id=1` just doesn't exist.

Comment: now http://127.0.0.1:8000/ this is showing that page not found but it does not show noreversematch error now what should i do?